# Having troubles updating to python 3.6 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: updates, python

I am trying to follow [these](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/07/install-python-3-6-1-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/) directions to upgrade my Python version to 3.6. I'm stuck on step 3. The command for Python 3.5 works fine but the second command for 3.6 is giving me the following error:

```
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/python3.6 doesn't exist
```

Comment: Can you type `ls /usr/bin | grep python` in a terminal and press enter? Do you see anything like `python3.6.1`?

Comment: No I don't. When I followed the previous steps it installed 3.6 correctly.

Comment: So python3.6 is there, it's just not running when you type `python3` or is it not running when you type `python3.6`?

Comment: no excuse me, it is not there. But I have no idea why it isn't i've tried installing 3.6 it a few times and it always unpacks and says done.

Comment: Can you run `apt list python3.6` and if it shows [installed,...] (where ... can be anything) then run `dpkg --listfiles python3.6`. Also run `python3 --version` to see if you might already have 3.6 running as your python3 version.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the python is located in .....

`/usr/local/bin/python3.6`

then the command ..

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.6 2
```